# How can we handle Null Values while Binding data to Text block in Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Hear i Have a confusion while Binding the data to Text Block in Windows phone

I have Text Block

```
<TextBlock Name="strytxt"
           Text="{Binding STORY}" 
            Height="auto" 
            Width="Auto" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

in STORY Object some time I have Empty/Null Values 
At that Time im Getting Some space in my UI

Now i Want to Make Visibility of the Textbox in to Collapsed if i get Null in that row 
How can i do this

Answer (score 3):

To change the Visibility of the TextBlock when the Binding value is null you need to use a Converter that converts from null/not null to Visible/Collapsed.

Here´s a converter that converts the values. The converter handles an empty string as null, so that it return `Collapsed` for `string.empty`.:

```
public class NullToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter {

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

    bool isVisible = value == null ? false : true;

    if (isVisible) {
      string stringValue = value as string;
      if (stringValue != null) {
        isVisible = string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue) ? false : true;
      }
    }

    if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool) {
      return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    return isVisible ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
  }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

You can apply the converter to the TextBlock as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <local:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter"/>
</userControl.Resources>

<TextBlock Name="strytxt"
           Visibility="{Binding STORY, Converter={StaticResource nullToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Another alternativ is to display a Text when the value is null, you can specify that in the binding

```
<TextBlock Name="strytxt"
           Text="{Binding STORY, TargetNullValue='is Null'}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a value converter to convert the value to a visibility:

```
public class NullToVisibiltyConverter : IValueConverter {

  public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    return value == null ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
  }

  public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

}
```

You then bind the `Visibility` of the `TextBlock` using the converter:

```
<TextBlock Name="strytxt"
  Text="{Binding STORY}" 
  Height="auto" 
  Width="Auto" 
  TextWrapping="Wrap"
  Visibility="{Binding STORY, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

You need to add an instance of the converter to a resource dictionary to be able to reference it in the binding:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <local:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter"/>
</userControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Which Namespace i want to add for local:NullToVisibilityConverter in my code

Comment: @SriramSatti: `System`, `System.Globalization`, `System.Windows` and `System.Windows.Data`.